# Open CV ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_uint32, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0

Tags: python, opencv, conda, undefined-symbol, libffi

I have installed OpenCV and when trying to import cv2 in python, I get the following error. The import was working fine until I installed/un-installed and re-installed tensor flow.

OpenCV has been installed in a conda environment using cmake.
Any idea how to fix this?

```
Python 3.10.9 (main, Jan 11 2023, 15:21:40) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/deleeps/anaconda3/envs/zscore/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/home/deleeps/anaconda3/envs/zscore/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 90, in bootstrap
    import cv2
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0: undefined symbol: ffi_type_uint32, version LIBFFI_BASE_7.0
>>> 


$ ldconfig -p | grep libwayland-client
    libwayland-client.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0
    libwayland-client.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so
    libwayland-client++.so.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client++.so.0
```

Answer (score 4):

I got around a similar issue by doing:

`export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7`

Answer (score 0):

I had to install (or maybe upgrade) the `cffi` package:

`python -m pip install -U cffi`